# Почему не срабатывает некластерный индекс?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexeddb

Есть пример простой таблицы без кластерного индекса или первичного ключа:

```
create table non_pk (a int, b int);
```

Для этой таблицы создан индекс:

```
create index non_pk_idx on non_pk (a, b);
```

Успешное создание которого подтверждает таблица индексов:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'non_pk'                                                                                                                                                ;
 schemaname | tablename | indexname  | tablespace |                       indexdef                       
------------+-----------+------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------
 public     | non_pk    | non_pk_idx |            | CREATE INDEX non_pk_idx ON non_pk USING btree (a, b)
```

Но после запросов по этим полям:

```
select * from non_pk where a = 4 and b = 5;
 a | b 
---+---
 4 | 5
(1 row)
```

Таблица статистики не показывает что при поиске по индексируемым полям был использован индекс:

```
select relname, seq_scan, idx_scan from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'non_pk';
 relname | seq_scan | idx_scan 
---------+----------+----------
 non_pk  |       10 |        0
(1 row)
```

Почему индекс не срабатывает и что нужно в такой ситуации чтобы поиск для запроса `select * from non_pk where a = 4 and b = 5;` использовал индекс `create index non_pk_idx on non_pk (a, b);`?

Comment: А сколько у вас записей в таблице ? БД не будет использовать индекс если посчитает, что прямым перебором искать быстрее. Для анализа работы с индексами добавьте в таблицу несколько тысяч записей. И используйте explain он скажет что и для чего БД собирается использовать

Comment: @Mike по поводу колличества записей это ценный совет у меня их там штуки 3 , хотя я пробовал аналогичную ситуацию с почти пустой таблицей и оно работало, а про explain если честно не понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL опирается на cost-based оптимизатор запросов. То есть для запроса создаётся сколько-то возможных планов выполнения, каждый имеет стоимость своего выполнения в некоторых попугаях. Затем выбирается тот вариант выполнения, который в попугаях получился дешевле. Не факт, что он быстрее остальных в действительности, но оптимизатор тоже должен быть быстрым, поэтому берётся ряд допущений, статистики, чёрной магии и обычно оно работает.

Поиск по индексу не всегда быстрее полного перебора таблицы. (и что в контексте этого вопроса важнее - не всегда дешевле с точки зрения планировщика) При том как для крошечных таблиц, так и для больших (особенно если вы хотите прочитать заметную часть таблицы), прыгать поиском по индексу может быть медленнее чем перебрать последовательно всё. И обычно планировщик решает верно. Поэтому имеет смысл сгенерировать какое-то число данных в таблицу, тысяч 10 строк, и тестировать хотя бы на такой малой выборке, но не на пустой таблице.

Форсировать использование индекса в запросе в PostgreSQL нельзя. Каких-либо хинтов планировщика нет и сообщество разработчиков явно отказывается добавлять такие, предпочитая получать багрепорты и исправлять при необходимости планировщик.

---

При рассмотрении конкретного запроса удобно использовать `explain`:

```
explain select * from non_pk where a = 4 and b = 5;
                                  QUERY PLAN                                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using non_pk_idx on non_pk  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8)
   Index Cond: ((a = 4) AND (b = 5))
```

`explain` покажет, что думает планировщик по этому запросу. Не менее (а часто и более) полезен `explain analyze`, который выполнит запрос и покажет, как это было:

```
explain analyze select * from non_pk where a = 4 and b = 5;
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using non_pk_idx on non_pk  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.046..0.046 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((a = 4) AND (b = 5))
   Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.101 ms
 Execution Time: 0.075 ms
```

Как видно, на моей системе планировщик решил использовать индекс.

Читать и понимать `explain`, впрочем, ближе к отдельному виду искусства. В сети есть много материалов по этому поводу, а вот формат ответа на побочный вопрос будет слишком узок для описания.

PS: в postgresql нет кластерных индексов (включая будущий релиз 12 версии). Даже если вы выполните команду `CLUSTER` - база не будет даже пытаться сохранять этот порядок в дальнейшем.

Comment: у меня получается что `Index Only Scan using p_index on non_pk` тоесть индекс все таки используется но в таблицу pg_stat_all_tables под именем idx_scan не записывается `select relname, seq_scan, idx_scan from pg_stat_all_tables where relname = 'non_pk';`
` relname | seq_scan | idx_scan 
---------+----------+----------
 non_pk  |        1 |        0`

Comment: explain (без analyze) не выполняет запрос, поэтому в pg_stat_all_tables вообще не меняется что-либо. Один наблюдаемый seq_scan относится вообще к `create index`, который выполняет последовательное чтение таблицы.